# Exact sequence arising from symplectic manifold

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a symplectic manifold, why is the following sequence exact?
$$0\to \mathbb{R} \to C^\infty (M)\to A\to 0$$
Here $A$ is the set of global Hamiltonian vector fields.

Comment: We can't tell you if it is exact or not if you don't tell us what the middle two maps are. I'm guessing the first is inclusion of the constant functions ($M$ is presumably connected) and the second is $f \mapsto X_f$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But why $M$ should be connected?

Comment: Hint: let $\phi: C^{\infty}(M)\rightarrow A$ be $f\mapsto \phi(f)=X_f$. The only non trivial part of your statement to prove is $\ker \phi=\mathbb R$. In other words, $X_f(g)=\{f,g\}=\omega(X_f,X_g)=0$ for all $g$ implies $f$ constant. You can express $X_f$, $X_g$ in local coordinates an arrive at the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $\phi:C^{\infty}(M)\rightarrow A$ be $f\mapsto \phi(f)=X_f$. The only non trivial part of your statement to prove is $\ker\phi=\mathbb R$. In other words, $X_f(g)=\{f,g\}=0$ for all $g$ implies $f$ constant. Here we consider $M$ to be connected.

Let $\omega=dq^i\wedge dp_i$ be the symplectic 2-form s and

$$X_f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}-
      \frac{\partial f}{\partial q^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}$$

be the Hamiltonian vector field $X_f$, both in canonical coordinate.

We want to prove that $X_f(g)=\{f,g\}=0$ for all $g\in C^{\infty}(M)$ implies $f$ constant.
Then

$$X_f(g)=\{f,g\}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}\frac{\partial g}{\partial q^i}-
      \frac{\partial f}{\partial q^i}\frac{\partial g}{\partial p_i}=0~~ (*)
    $$ 
for all $g$ implies

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^i}=0,$$

for all $i=1,\dots,2n$. We chose $g=q^j$ and $g=p_j$ for all $j$'s in (*).
The statement follows.

Comment: Avitus@ Thanks for the nice answer

Comment: @h.jolany You are welcome. $M$ is supposed to be connected. This implies that a function with all vanishing derivatives is constant (i.e. each function specifies a unique real number $\mathbb R$). If $M$ admitted multiple connected components then a function with vanishing derivatives would be constant on each connected component, with possibly different values on each of them, though.

Comment: ohhh, Yes, thank for this precision and accuracy